# Rellenar parte de una matriz con forma de circulo

Tags: matrices, lenguaje-agnóstico

Mi duda es como podria crear un circulo dentro de una matriz. Me explico:

Imaginemos una matriz 1000x1000, llena de 0. Ya tengo el codigo necesario para crear rectangulos y rombos (rellenar de 1 las casillas necesarias con esa forma). Pero mi duda es como podria rellenar la matirz con unos con una forma semejante a un circulo.

El lenguaje de programacion me da igual, solo quiero la idea .

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Edit: la matriz de 1000x1000 es un ejemplo, pero siempre van  a ser tamaños donde pueda ser concebido una buena aproximacion(100x100....).
Simplemente es la manera de llenar de unas una matriz de ceros con forma de circulo.

Comment: Bienvenido ya que tu pregunta es muy amplia te invito a leer [ask] para que puedas mostrar algo mas especifico

Comment: ¿La dimensión de tu matriz siempre va a ser 1000x1000? Ya que si tenemos una matriz de 2x2, tu pregunta no tiene sentido. Si puedes poner más información sobre tu problema, podríamos ayudar más :)

Comment: Edito ahora mismo

Comment: Para ese problema lo importante es el radio del circulo. Una vez que tienes el radio es cuestión de poner en 1 las posiciones de la matriz en donde la distancia entre una posición X de la matriz y el origen del circulo es menor o igual al radio.

Comment: podrias ver el siguiente articulo de wikipedia: [algoritmo del punto medio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_del_punto_medio_para_circunferencias)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto te formaría un círculo relleno de 1, la pregunta es un poco ambigua asi que no estoy muy seguro si es el resultado que buscas.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] matriz = new int[9][];
    double medio = (matriz.length-1)/2.0;
    for (int columna = 0; columna < matriz.length; columna++)
    {
        int[] fila = new int[matriz.length];
        double yy = columna-medio;
        for (int x=0; x<fila.length; x++)
        {
           double xx = x-medio;
           if (Math.sqrt(xx*xx+yy*yy)<=medio)
             fila[x] = 1;
           System.out.print(fila[x]);
        }
        matriz[columna] = fila;
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

La fórmula de la circunferencia es f(x,y)=x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> - r<sup>2</sup>, centrada en 0,0;

Supongamos que el diámetro de la circunferencia sea el ancho de la matriz: una matriz de 101 x 101 tendrá un círculo de 50 celdas de radio, y el centro estará en la posición 50,50.

La solución sería, para cada columna, calcular qué filas están dentro de la circunferencia:

- Para la columna 0: r=50, x=-50 -> y=0;
- Para la columna 1: r=50, x=-49 -> y<sup>2</sup>= 2500-2401 -> y = (9,-9) aproximadamente, por lo que habría que pintar entre las posiciones 41 y 59
- Para la columna 2: x=-48 -> y<sup>2</sup>=2500 - 2304= 196 -> y =14, -14
- ...

Te pongo un ejemplo en Javascript que, por simplicidad, hace el cálculo por filas en lugar de por columnas (conceptualmente rotado 90º respecto a la explicación anterior) y con un tamaño menor:

```js
let matrix = [];

const RADIO = 25;
const DIAMETRO = RADIO * 2;

function calculaX(radio, y) {
  return Math.round(((radio ** 2) - ((y-radio) ** 2)) ** .5);
}

for (let y = 0; y < DIAMETRO; y++){
   const limite= calculaX(RADIO, y);
   matrix[y] = [];
   for (let x = 0; x < DIAMETRO; x++) {
     matrix[y].push(((x < RADIO - limite) || (x > RADIO + limite)) ? ' ' : '0');
   }
}

for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
  console.log(matrix[i].toString());
}
```